# iOS push segues not keeping data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm doing something silly here but for the life of me i cannot see it.

**Push from ViewControllerA to ViewController B:** No transfer of data.

**Segue back from ViewControllerB to ViewController A:** Data transfers.

**Push from ViewControllerA to ViewController B:** Previous labels and datepicker values are reset and do not stay as previously selected.

How do i get ViewControllerB labels to stay as they previously were?

I know it is something obvious, i would appreciate your extra sets of eyes!

Let me know if you need more information or anything.

Comment: Thanks peoples! All answers were helpful but best way to do it seems to be through state control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to remember the state and transfer the data from A to B, and have the labels and values set in B's `viewDidLoad:` or somewhere else convenient.

When ViewControllerB is popped off the navigation stack, the entire object is deallocated. As you're noticing, a fresh ViewControllerB is initialized each time.

Answer (score 0):

When ViewControllerB call back ViewControllerA, ViewControllerA was deallocated before, so that you can not push back data from viewcotrollerB to view controllerA. 
I think in this case, you can using delegate patter. Please show this question to see more detail [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

I think "Unwind Segues" will be the best solution for you. Take a look on the link below:

http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them